# Different environments for Lambda Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I currently have a few lambda functions that interact with an application inside Elastic Beanstalk. These functions use environment variables that are specific to Staging env. Since I am now going to start moving some things to production, I wanted to know good and practical ways of handling these functions, that is:

- Should I copy this function into another function and set different env variables?
- Is there a way to have different environments in one unique function?
- Should I use runtime variables?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I copy this function into another function and set different
> env variables?

Yes, but you should really be doing this via something like CloudFormation or Terraform instead of copying it manually.

> Is there a way to have different environments in one unique function?

No

Comment: Thank you! I am using terraform :)

Comment: @VitorCarvalho if using Terraform I suggest using workspaces, so you deploy the function once to your `dev` workspace, and then a second time to your `prod` workspace, without having to duplicate any code or configuration.